# In akka actor if the message is exception how to call the same for few time with fixed interval between them

Tags: java, akka, actor, akka-http

I have an utility class from which I am calling a service api. If everything is fine I will get desired output which is in string format.So that's success case. But It may happen that I get an error suppose 404 if the server is down.In such cases I want to call that api for suppose 3 times with 1 second interval between them. If within these three retries I get success from the Api then I will not cal the api and log the result, Or if after 3 retries it still throws error then I will not continue and just log the error.
my Utility class

```
public class Utils {

public void doOperation(String service_Url) throws Exception {
    Object message= someFunction(service_Url);//this function is calling the service api
    final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("helloakka");
    final ActorRef akkaBot=system.actorOf(Props.create(MyUntypedActor.class), "akkaBot");
    akkaBot.tell(message, ActorRef.noSender());
}

}
```

Here is the Actor

```
public class MyUntypedActor extends UntypedActor {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof HTTPException) {
      System.out.println(message);
      //Here as it got exception.I want to call the actor 3 times with 1 second interval between them 
    } 
else if (message instanceof String) {
      System.out.println(message);
      getSender().tell(value, getSelf());
    }
else {
      unhandled(message);
    }
  }
}
```

The objective is test a particular api is working or not using akka actor.If the api returns exception then call that api using actor 3 times with 1 sec interval between each call.If after 3 times we are still getting error then then log the error,if while retrying we get desired output then log it.

I don't know how to achieve it using akka actors.Please guide me if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for can be accomplished with a slight modification of your code organization.  It would be easier for your Actor to do all of the querying rather than just the queries subsequent to a failure.

You'll first need some way of representing the failures:

```
public class RequestFailure {
  public String request;
  public int count;

  public RequestFailure(String r, int c) {
    request = r;
    count = c;
  }
}
```

This class can then be a message type sent to your Actor which will act accordingly:

```
public class MyUntypedActor extends UntypedActor {
  public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if(message instanceOf String) {
       Object response = someFunction( (String) message);
       if(response instanceOf HTTPException) {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         getSelf().tell(new RequestFailure((String) message, 1), getSender());
       } 
       else
         getSender().tell(response, getSelf())
    }
    else if(message instanceOf RequestFailure) {
      RequestFailure rf = (RequestFailure) message;
      if(rf.count <= 3) {
        Object response = someFunction(rf.request);
        if(response instanceOf HTTPException) {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          getSelf().tell(new RequestFailure(rf.request, rf.count + 1), getSender();
        } 
        else
          getSender().tell(response, getSelf())
        }
      } 
      else
        //FIXME : question doesn't specify what to return 
        //        if max count reached   
    }
  }
}
```

You would then ask the `Actor` with a request `String` to start the process.

Comment: if its success for the first time, it works as desired.But if at the first attempt it's an error then it creates RequestFailure object and calls the second time using rf.request.If the second time(or in any attempt) its success then as its not an instance of exception so `getSender().tell(response, getSelf());` is executed. But here what is happening is `public void onReceive(Object message) {` method of `class MyUntypedActor` is receiving the response what `getSender().tell` is sending and the actor is executed again and again.same is happening when count>3 and else send getSender() @Ramon J

Comment: @MithunDebnath Answer updated.  I was referencing the `MyUntypedActor` as the sender of the original request instead of the actual sender.  Let me know if you see any other problems...

Comment: I will test the code tomorrow as I don't have the application with me right now.One thing I noticed but I forget to ask you.`if(rf.count <= 3) {Object response = someFunction(rf.request);`here if `if(response instanceOf HTTPException) {` then you have written `getSelf().tell(new RequestFailure((String) message, rf.count + 1), getSender();` isn't it should be `getSelf().tell(new RequestFailure((String) rf.request, rf.count + 1), getSender();`.Another thing is if count reached max number I want to send the actual sender the information that `max count reached`.From which else I send it?@ Ramon

Comment: @Ramon my requirement is also of same type.Hope Ramon's reply will resolve it for me also.

Comment: @MithunDebnath You are correct about the revision, I have updated my answer.